# Refused to execute script - Strict Mime type

Tags: apache, syntax-error, mediawiki, mime-types, php-5.5

Newbie to mediawiki, so apologies if this is a simple error.

I have a local working fine, but on my remote (addon domain, installed in the root of that) my mediawiki install keeps giving me the console error of:

```
Refused to execute script from 
'http://host.co.uk/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=notify%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.legacy.wikibits&skin=vector&version=5e0d755bcceb' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

that's in google chrome. But in Firefox i'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

This error is on line  1 and points to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I'm thinking because it's trying to load html, not JS?

When I initially actioned the install, I wasn't getting any css, I solved this issue setting the `session.save_path` to a writeable directory.

The page URL on going to the root of the site is different from local to remote. This is because my remote uses CGI which apparently breaks the short urls: see mediaWiki: `$wgUsePathInfo`

`local: /index.php/Main_Page`

`remote: /index.php?title=Main_Page`

I've considered the byte order issues for LocalSettings.php, by saving in vim and checking for a space or dot before `<?php`, but alas no solution.

**My error is described here perfectly**, but being on a dedicated VPS and looking at the markup, I'm confident there is no code for tracking or advertising being injected automatically - could there be another cause?
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms#Missing_edit_toolbar.2C_JavaScript_not_working

The errors do change when I switch from using suPHP as my handler. Changing to FCGI I'm able to get the firefox syntax error `expected expression but got <` in google chrome and some errors printed to the page of:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_cf912e9c546f88005f99ad715791fe84, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

I am confused as whilst the least errors come from suPHP, looking in php info it says my php api is CGI/FastCGI

I am using MediaWiki 1.26, php 5.5.3, Apache 2.2.31, CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 - any further details please just ask.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I've missed anything.

**UPDATE**

The url which is giving the console error:

`/load.php?debug=true&lang=en&modules=j…notify%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.legacy.wikibit‌​s&skin=vector&version=10de47153c1c`

returns this javascript object:

`mw.loader.state ({ 
   "j…notify": "missing", 
   "util": "missing", 
   "mediawiki.legacy.wikibit‌​s": "missing" 
})`

**UPDATE 2**

To show any details that perhaps I'm missing I show a screen on the dev tools.

[image: Sources Tab]
[image: Network Tab]

but also, on going to the concerned url again, it's now spitting out further information. I believe the information has changed because in my desperation I did `composer install` and reploaded the `/vendor` directory:

`mw.loader.implement( "mediawiki.legacy.wikibits", [
    "/resources/src/mediawiki.legacy/wikibits.js"
] );
mw.loader.state( {
    "j…notify": "missing",
    "util": "missing"
} );`

**UPDATE 3**

[image: text/html content type on network Tab - 2]

**UPDATE 4**
Following along the advice from @TGR, I looked at the url in the network tab giving content type text/html. The part that confused me is that it doesn't match the url giving the error. However it does return 302. Looking at the same url on my local install returns:

```
mw.loader.implement( "jquery.accessKeyLabel", [
        "/resources/src/jquery/jquery.accessKeyLabel.js"
    ], {}, {"brackets":"[$1]","word-separator":" "} 
);
mw.loader.implement(        
    "jquery.client", [
    "/resources/lib/jquery.client/jquery.client.js"
] );
mw.loader.implement( "mediawiki.RegExp", [
    "/resources/src/mediawiki/mediawiki.RegExp.js"
] );
mw.loader.implement( "mediawiki.notify", [
    "/resources/src/mediawiki/mediawiki.notify.js"
] );
mw.loader.implement( "mediawiki.util", [
    "/resources/src/mediawiki/mediawiki.util.js"
] );
mw.loader.implement( "mediawiki.legacy.wikibits", [
    "/resources/src/mediawiki.legacy/wikibits.js"
] );
```

I can also confirm that those files in the above code block are present on the problematic wiki.

**UPDATE 5**

I have just done a new install of the media wiki at a different subdomain. This time rather than FTP I have SSH into the server a ran `wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.26/mediawiki-1.26.2.tar.gz` and then `tar xvzf mediawiki-1.26.2.tar.gz`. This leaves me with folder 'mediawiki-1.26.2'. I then `cd mediawiki-1.26.2` followed by `mv * ../` so that the wiki will work from the root. The last thing to do before I can run the install, is to correct the permissions. `chown -R user:group *`

I then run the install which goes very smoothly. When I get to the homepage and inspect the developer console I get the same error. This is completely fresh, no .htaccess or .conf

**UPDATE 6**
I felt as though there was some longevity in exploring the install directory. So on my own VPS I followed the install above, again moving files to the Root. I didn't get the same error, but I did get
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`
I then installed again but I left it in the subfolder of the root. This has not given me any errors. I then tried this on the live remote that i've been having issues with. Even installed in the subfolder this gives me:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`
If I introduce a .htaccess file to rewrite the base url, such as `RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mw/index.php [L]`, then the issue with MIME type text/html returns. Yet adding the same rule on my other install is error free.

Comment: If you get HTML instead of JS, chances are either it's giving you some kind of error page, or your web server configuration is messed up and the URL is not actually handled by load.php.

Comment: @Tgr - thanks. My bet would be on some server setting, though the wiki itself is functioning fine. I can post, navigate etc. It's stuff like the wikiEditor wysiwyg that's not showing as a result of this error.

Comment: `load.php` is used to load Javascript/CSS, so it won't affect basic functionality but break everything else.

Comment: @Tgr would your money be on a incorrect php module? I've switched to Nginx, but still having the same issue. Also the install is in the root, I've read in quite a few articles this can cause issues - Thanks

Comment: What does the HTML page contain? A quick way to check if `load.php` is even executed is to put `die;` at the beginning and see if the HTML page is replaced by a white screen of death.

Comment: @Tgr – It's occurring on every page, from `/index.php?title=Main_Page` to `/index.php?title=Special:Preferences`. I'm not sure if you meant me to add `die;` to the editor, so it's output as HTML or a template, but assumed the later as I suspect you're assuming it would not be translated as HTML but parsed and die if there's an error. It did in fact render correctly.

Comment: To `load.php` since that's the URL where you actually get an error. All else is just the side effect of `load.php` included in the page as Javascript (that's what it's used for) but actually being a HTML page.

Comment: @Tgr Got you. That makes sense now. So putting `die;` at the top of the page strips all styling. Looking in the console, the error is now replaced with a number of `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html` errors. However all markup is rendered.

Comment: This is the url that it's struggling with btw: `/load.php?debug=true&lang=en&modules=j…notify%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.legacy.wikibits&skin=vector&version=10de47153c1c`

Comment: So what does that URL actually return?

Comment: sorry, yes that would be useful:
`mw.loader.state (
{
"j…notify": "missing",
"util": "missing",
"mediawiki.legacy.wikibit‌​s": "missing"
}
)`

Comment: Are you sure that's the URL that gives the error? That seems entirely fine. Just to be sure though, you can try `curl -vso /dev/null 'URL' |& grep Content-Type:` which will tell you what the content type is. (Or you can look it up in the browser's developer toolbar's network panel.)

Comment: Please see update 2 for developer tool screen shots. The command you asked me to run, doesn't return anything. Thanks again @Tgr for all your help.

Comment: Can you select the URL giving the errors in the network tab (the one with text/html in the 'Type' column) and take a screenshot of that?

Comment: @Tgr as requested, though none of the URLs match the one giving the error. Did you want the headers tab? Thanks

Comment: @Tgr I've just looked at the problem URL on my local install again, which isn't outputting the error, and it's giving me exactly the same js output as in update 2. Surely this must be a server config issue. Some missing package? Though i've checked and double checked the install server guidelines.

Comment: 302 Found is a redirect response (with the Location header telling where it got redirected). Does it redirect to the wrong place? (Do all other load.php requests redirect as well?) Does it match some nginx rewrite rule maybe?

Comment: The server that hosts this initially used Aapche and we've now switched to nginx and installed varnish, though apache is still installed. This issue has been apparent through all of the phases when using apache through to nginx and then still whilst adding varnish. We haven't added an nginx rewrites yet, but I did initially try this htacess rule suggested in a forum, whilst on Apache to no avail: `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(api|load)\.php - [L]`

Comment: @Tgr I've gone back to square one and done a seperate installation on the same server.. see Update 5/6. http://wiki.titan.anglingdirect.co.uk/mw/

Comment: @Tgr I had to leave this for a while, but upon coming back to this issue I passed it to our hosting provider. It ended up being a mod_security server issue whereby the request was being refused. Upon resolving this the mediaWiki is now working as expected. Thanks for your help.